# Python Pandas: use map function on iterator

Tags: python, xml, pandas, iterator, map-function

Maybe an easy question for some of you.

I'm parsing an XML tree, that has a quite complex and nested structure. This is part of the code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

tree = ET.parse('input_data.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for unit in root.iter('xml_element_name'):
    # do something with the unit
```

But I would like to get rid of the for-each iteration, since I would like to use a map function (e.g. Pandas.Series.map or Pandas.Dataframe.map or any similar). So this is pseudo-code that I would like to achieve:

```
items = pd.Series(root.iter('xml_element_name'))
df = pd.Dataframe(items.map(lambda unit: ....))
```

But how? Any idea?

**PS:** A sample XML can be found in the [tutorial of the ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).

**Why** do I want to do this? Because I want to switch to PySpark later on so that each XMLElement (unit) is handled in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to create a flat data structure out of the iterator via:

```
flat_list = list(root.iter())
```

and then create a DataFrame out of it.

Here's the full snippet:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import pdb

tree = ET.parse('cd_catalog.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

flat_list = list(root.iter())
df        = pd.DataFrame({'xml_elements':flat_list})

# do some arbitrary computation on the df:
result = df.xml_elements.map(lambda x: x.text) 
print(result.head(n=3))
```

(link to the [xml file](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml))

Comment: This works. Even though it's a good idea to split the first element (hierarchy) on the first run already. Meaning that you could get more than one column when calling root.iter() thus either creating a dictionary or a series.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing excuses you from knowing the structure of the document you are parsing.  With you example you referenced, you can use a combination of a list and dictionary comprehensions to pass something to the `pd.DataFrame` constructor.

Hopefully this gives you and idea

```
pd.DataFrame([
    {a.tag: a.text for a in c if a.tag != 'neighbor'}
    for c in root.findall('country')
])

    gdppc rank  year
0  141100    1  2008
1   59900    4  2011
2   13600   68  2011
```

Comment: Not an easy code. Especially the contructor of the dataframe that you used. But I understand I guess. Remark: the XML that I'm parsing, is a bit more complex. btw: your code is still using for-each inside the constructor.

Comment: @Matthias but generally speaking, comprehensions seem to be quicker.  In the same vein, so is `map`.

Comment: I ended up using your code, while the other one above works too. `df = pd.DataFrame([(child.tag, child.attrib) for child in root.iter('country')])`and `df.columns = ['tag', 'attributes']`